# Rcpp function cannot be found by R

Tags: r, package, rstudio, rcpp, devtools

I built an `R` `package` (called `myUtils`), which uses a `cpp` file, in `RStudio` following [Hadley's manual](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/src.html). My `cpp` file resides in the `src` directory, created after running: `devtools::use_rcpp()`, and under my `R` directory I have a file called `myUtils.R`, with these lines:

```
#' myUtils: A package with various functions for my analyses
#'
#'
#' @docType package
#' @name myUtils
#' @useDynLib myUtils
#' @importFrom Rcpp sourceCpp
NULL
```

Here's my `cpp` file:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo, RcppEigen)]]

#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppEigen.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP armaMatMult(arma::mat A, arma::mat B){
  arma::mat C = A * B;

  return Rcpp::wrap(C);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP eigenMatMult(Eigen::MatrixXd A, Eigen::MatrixXd B){
  Eigen::MatrixXd C = A * B;

  return Rcpp::wrap(C);
}
```

I then ran `devtools::document()` which added `useDynLib(myUtils)` to the `NAMESPACE` file. I then ran `Build & Reload`, which finished successfully, and created the `RccpExports.R` file in the `R` directory, with the `cpp` functions in it, for example:

```
eigenMatMult <- function(A, B) {
    .Call('_myUtils_eigenMatMult', PACKAGE = 'myUtils', A, B)
}
```

Then I tried to test `eigenMatMult` but it's not recognized:

```
set.seed(1)
A <- matrix(rnorm(100), 10, 10)
> eigenMatMult(A=A,B=A)
Error: could not find function "eigenMatMult"
```

and neither comes up when preceded by `myUtils::`

Looks like I'm missing something but I can't figure out what it is.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suggested you file a bug report with Dr Wickham and/or his bug site.  RcppArmadillo works; move the book away and start from `RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton()` which we provide, test and document.  Cheers.

Comment: You of course also need to _build_ the package `myUtils` and _load_ it.  You question is unclear as to whether you did or not.

Comment: The last thing I did before testing the function is Build & Reload - it's in my post

Comment: Do you have a `NAMESPACE` file?  Again, our skeleton will provide you a _working_ example.

Comment: Yep, a NAMESPACE file was created which includes: useDynLib(myUtils) in it

Comment: Does it have an `export` line?

Comment: Only to the functions in my R file but not in my cpp file. I'm assuming that since I don't have the @export roxygen documentation in my cpp file is the reason they're not in NAMESPACE and not recognized?

Comment: Read the Rcpp Attributes vignette if you are unclear. Maybe what you need here (as a shortcut) is `myUtils:::eigenMatMult(A, A)` -- with three colons.  Export that functions, else you cannot call it.

Comment: Both are correct. Thanks!

Comment: Let me provide this as answer then and it would be kind if you could accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Rcpp Attributes mechanism does not by itself add functions to the export directive in the `NAMESPACE` file.  Our example uses a wildcard to export everything.

So if your function is not visible, do either or both of

- call via `:::` ie `myUtils:::eigenMatMult(A, A)`
- add `eigenMatMult` to exports, either by hand or via a roxygen tag

Answer (score 2):

Dirk said:

> add `eigenMatMult` to exports, either by hand or via a roxygen tag

We probably don't want to modify `NAMESPACE` by hand if it is generated by roxygen2:

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand
```

So, let's add a tag for roxygen2, so it knows to add our function automatically to the `NAMESPACE` file.

Your code example looks like this:

```cpp
// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP eigenMatMult(Eigen::MatrixXd A, Eigen::MatrixXd B){
  Eigen::MatrixXd C = A * B;

  return Rcpp::wrap(C);
}
```

It should look like this instead (notice the line with `//' @export`):

```cpp
//' @export
// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP eigenMatMult(Eigen::MatrixXd A, Eigen::MatrixXd B){
  Eigen::MatrixXd C = A * B;

  return Rcpp::wrap(C);
}
```

Comment: will this work for any R package that uses .cpp files?